# aws domain alias not resolving

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I registered a Domain on AWS and setup a hosted zone for it.
I want to resolve my domain `www.something.com` on a third party website which is hosted under `https://www.example.com`

I understand the principle of cnaming but something is not working right and I don't understand why.

So I have declared the CNAME correctly as value `https://www.example.com`.
Now when doing `dig www.something.com` I get the following response:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.something.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39539
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.something.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.something.com.  300 IN  CNAME   https://www.example.com.
https://www.example.com. 751    IN A    46.30.215.88

;; Query time: 57 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.178.1#53(192.168.178.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Aug 11 21:34:22 CEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
```

which looks to me that the CNAME is correctly resolving.
But my client gives me the following:

for [www.something.com](http://www.something.com) I receive:

```
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

trying https://www.something.com I get:

```
* Connected to www.something.com (46.30.215.88) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* error:14004410:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14004410:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I have waited 24h+ but the issue remains.
I have connected the host provider for https://www.example.com and they claim that the CNAME I set is the correct one.

I am out of ideas now as this is a very simple task. Just that I cannot resolve the ALIAS correctly.

Comment: The value of CNAME record should be host name, not URL.

Answer (score 0):

As this is returning a 404 it confirms that it is actually resolving to a host.

Just to confirm the value should be the domain name by itself (do not include protocols or paths, it should be `example.com` not `https://example.com`).

You can test this locally by overriding your local hosts file to resolve the targeted domain to a specific IP address (such as the one in your `DIG` command)

If you believe the `CNAME` is correct then you should try to contact whoever provided this to you to validate that they are receiving the request on their end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - trying the blank URL also now. How is this working with SSL then? I tried this with heroku DNS before and it was working fine without an additional certificate on AWS

Comment: AWS Route 53 is only for DNS, not application hosting so the SSL error is being returned by the host :(